# Master/slave using Oracle

Tags: activemq-classic

we're using the so called **JDBC Master Slave** architecture with Oracle DB. We have 2 nodes and each one has one Broker started. We start the Broker1 (on node1) and it becomes the MASTER obtaining the lock over the tables. Then we start the Broker2 on the node2 and this one starts as SLAVE. WE can see in the log of Slave broker that it's trying to obtain the lock every 10sec, but it fails:

```
2013-06-12 19:32:38,714 | INFO  | Default failed to acquire lease.  Sleeping for 10000 milli(s) before trying again... | org.apache.activemq.store.jdbc.LeaseDatabaseLocker | main
2013-06-12 19:32:48,720 | INFO  | Default Lease held by Default till Wed Jun 12 19:32:57 UTC 2013 | org.apache.activemq.store.jdbc.LeaseDatabaseLocker | main
```

Everything works fine and then in one moment in SLAVE's log we see that it suddenly becomes the MASTER:

```
2013-06-13 00:38:11,262 | INFO  | Default Lease held by Default till Thu Jun 13 00:38:17 UTC 2013 | org.apache.activemq.store.jdbc.LeaseDatabaseLocker | main
2013-06-13 00:38:11,262 | INFO  | Default failed to acquire lease.  Sleeping for 10000 milli(s) before trying again... | org.apache.activemq.store.jdbc.LeaseDatabaseLocker | main
...
2013-06-13 00:38:21,314 | INFO  | Default, becoming the master on dataSource: org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource@9c6a99d | org.apache.activemq.store.jdbc.LeaseDatabaseLocker | main
2013-06-13 00:38:21,576 | INFO  | Apache ActiveMQ 5.8.0 (Default, ID:corerec3-49774-1371083901328-0:1) is starting | org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService | main
2013-06-13 00:38:21,692 | WARN  | Failed to start jmx connector: Cannot bind to URL [rmi://localhost:1616/jmxrmi]: javax.naming.NameAlreadyBoundException: jmxrmi [Root exception is java.rmi.AlreadyBoundException: jmxrmi]. Will restart management to re-create jmx connector, trying to remedy this issue. | org.apache.activemq.broker.jmx.ManagementContext | JMX connector
2013-06-13 00:38:21,700 | INFO  | Listening for connections at: tcp://corerec3:61617?transport.closeAsync=false | org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportServerThreadSupport | main
2013-06-13 00:38:21,700 | INFO  | Connector openwire Started | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnector | main
2013-06-13 00:38:21,701 | INFO  | Apache ActiveMQ 5.8.0 (Default, ID:corerec3-49774-1371083901328-0:1) started | org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService | main
2013-06-13 00:38:21,701 | INFO  | For help or more information please see: http://activemq.apache.org | org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService | main
2013-06-13 00:38:21,701 | ERROR | Memory Usage for the Broker (512 mb) is more than the maximum available for the JVM: 245 mb | org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService | main
2013-06-13 00:38:22,157 | INFO  | Web console type: embedded | org.apache.activemq.web.WebConsoleStarter | main
2013-06-13 00:38:22,292 | INFO  | ActiveMQ WebConsole initialized. | org.apache.activemq.web.WebConsoleStarter | main
2013-06-13 00:38:22,353 | INFO  | Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher' | /admin | main
```

while the MASTER's log shows no change from what it usually outputs...

So, it seems that somehow SLAVE obtains the lock (due to hmm... for example connection loss between master and the DB), but if we don't restart the brokers we start losing messages...

The problem is that in the producers' log we can see that it successfully sends the messages to the *QueueX*, but we don't see the consumer's taking them from the queue... 
If we go to the DB and query _ACTIVEMQ_MSGS_ table we see that the messages are unprocessed. 
It looks as if the broker (Producers are connected to) has the lock and inserts the messages into the DB and the brokers Clients are consuming from doesn't have the lock and can't consult the tables...

I don't know if all this makes much sense, but I surely hope someone might shed some light upon this one...

I didn't want to saturate the post with the configuration details, but if you need specific details like failover config, IPs, ports etc. I will post it...

Comment: Not sure about the lock issue, but you might want to fix this:

`2013-06-13 00:38:21,701 | ERROR | Memory Usage for the Broker (512 mb) is more than the maximum available for the JVM: 245 mb | org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService | main`

Comment: I doubt this is causing the Slave becoming Master problem, but we'll surely want to fix this :) thanks

Comment: Prob. not, but memory problems have a nasty habit of causing any kind of weired errors in any software.

Comment: btw, see if you can have some debug level logging when reproducing the error. It might give you more info to track down the issue